# How would I get this nested list to be formatted cleanly/correctly in scheme?

Tags: list, append, scheme, racket

I want to have these lists returned in the expected format `(() () () ())` but it ends up looking like `((((()))))` what combinations of list and append would make this work? Or is there some extra built in function that will help?

Here's the code:

```
(define p-loop
  (lambda (row col triangle)
    (if (= row 0)
        triangle
        (if (= col 0)
            (p-loop (- row 1) (- row 1) (append (list triangle)))
            (p-loop row (- col 1) (append triangle (list (p-nums row col))))))))
```

(`p-nums` returns a single number)

`(p-loop 4 4 '())` ideally would return

```
((1 3 3 1) (1 2 1) (1 1) (1))
```

but it ends up looking like

```
(((((1 3 3 1) 1 2 1) 1 1) 1))
```

Comment: There's no point in calling `append` with a single argument. It just returns the same list.

Comment: @Barmar I was moving around a lot of code chunks, trying out different things, and that just got accidentally left over from a different attempt

Comment: I suggest you split this into two functions. Move the code that generates a row into its own function, then call that in a loop, creating a list of the results.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who happened to have this very specific issue I figured it out with the help of someone in person after formatting it in the way Barmar's comment suggested:

```
(define p-loop
  (lambda (row col triangle)
    (if (= row 0)
        triangle
        (p-loop (- row 1) (- row 1) 
              (append triangle (list (p-row row row '())))))))

(define p-row
  (lambda (row col rowlist)
    (if (= col 0)
       rowlist
       (p-row row (- col 1) 
           (append rowlist (list (p-nums row col)))))))
```